# unknown_host issue in ejabberd websocket

Tags: websocket, xmpp, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd on EC2 with hostname like my `myejbdomain.com` and have integrated with my project with websocket like `wss://myejbdomain.com:5280/websocket`

It is working properly without SSL or on the local but not on the site on like mydomain.com, it returns `err StreamError: host-unknown` error. I doubt its a CORS issue but not sure, please help me to resolve the issue. Following is my configuration

```
hosts:
  - mydomain.com


loglevel: 5

#ca_file: "/opt/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

certfiles:
  - "/etc/ejabberd/certs/*/*.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
    port: 5223
    ip: "::"
    tls: true
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
      /upload: mod_http_upload
      /ws: ejabberd_http_ws
      /wss: ejabberd_http_ws
      /websocket: ejabberd_http_ws
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /xmpp: ejabberd_http_ws
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      /ws: ejabberd_http_ws
      /wss: ejabberd_http_ws
      /websocket: ejabberd_http_ws
      /.well-known/acme-challenge: ejabberd_acme
  -
    port: 3478
    ip: "::"
    transport: udp
    module: ejabberd_stun
    use_turn: true
    ## The server's public IPv4 address:
    # turn_ipv4_address: "203.0.113.3"
    ## The server's public IPv6 address:
    # turn_ipv6_address: "2001:db8::3"
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acme:
  auto: false

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
  admin:
    user: admin@bkstg
  apicommands:
    user: admin@bkstg
access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          - acl: loopback
          - acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number
  "some playing":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
      - mod_http_api
    who:
      acl: apicommands
    what: "*"
shaper:
  normal:
    rate: 3000
    burst_size: 20000
  fast: 100000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
    custom_headers:
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://@HOST@"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    host: mydomain.com
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_stun_disco: {}
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, it may be the problem, or maybe it's some other thing:

You tell ejabberd to server the domain `mydomain.com`:

```
hosts:
  - mydomain.com
```

But later your client connects to ejabberd and asks to login to `myejbdomain.com`, which is another domain that ejabberd does not know anything at all ?

```
wss://myejbdomain.com:5280/websocket
```

If I understand this correctly, it makes sense that ejabberd complains `host-unknown`... ejabberd does not know the `myejbdomain.com` :)